# Push selective commits from Dev to Prod branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Problem:
I have a `dev` branch. It includes bug fixes, new features,  not to be released features.
and I have a `prod` branch. It contains released features, bug fixes.

Requirement: I would like to push selective commits from dev to the prod branch.

How to do it?

Extra Info:
I've read about git cherry pick. It requires merging back to dev branch for some reason. I would like to know if there is a better to do it?
I am using VSCode editor.(If there is some integration for this editor it would be awesome)

Answer (score 0):

Cherry-picking is your friend.

Do the following:

1. `git fetch` - to get the latest branches
2. `git log origin/dev --pretty=format:"%H,%ad,%s,,,%an%n" | tail -20000000r` - this will print the list of commits to dev branch (you can change the formatting by your desire), pick which commits you want to merge
3. `git checkout prod` - to get to your prod branch
4. `git cherry-pick [hash-of-desired-commit]` - this will merge the commit to the branch
5. `git push origin prod` - push the change to prod branch

I strongly encourage you to do cherry-pick -> push for every commit.

Plus - if your cherry-picking have some conflicts - stop, and run `git reset --hard`, then use some program to solve the conflicts (I use IntelliJ for that), after resolving, push and continue.

Comment: Just a note. I would make a new branch off of prod named something like release, cherrypick into that branch, then merge that branch with production. Don't push directly to prod

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 options:

1. Create new branch and then `cherry-pick` needed commits.
2. Use `rebase` to reorder commits (if needed) and then just push needed amount of them.

1st solution is quite simple and straightforward but has one important cons I don't like — when you use cherry-pick — new commit with different hash is created, so if you go this way and push/merge newly crated branch with cherry-picked commits to `prod` you have to clean your local `dev` from commits that were cherry-picked and pushed (via `rebase` or using new branch and `cherry-pick`).

2ns solution is more sophisticated, the one I personally prefer and use.

Imagine, we have 2 branches and several commits:

```
prod   a
        \
dev      b---c---d---e
```

There could be 2 situations:

1. You want to push commits that are directly based on `prod` (e.g. `b` and `c`)
2. You want to push commits from the middle or from the end while keeping first commits not published (e.g. `d` and `e`).

For the first case you can simply do:

```
git push origin HEAD~2:prod
```

Means all commits except of last 2 will be published to prod. I'm using HEAD to find some previous commits from log, but you can also use commit hash.

Second case is a little bit tricky. Idea is that firstly you have to reorder your commits in such way that you could apply same command from above. For example, you want to push only `d` and `e` commits.

First part is to reorder commits:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

When editor opens you need to just change the commits order to make it following:

```
prod   a
        \
dev      d--e--a--b
```

After reorder is finished, you can reuse same command:

```
git push origin HEAD~2:prod
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've read about git cherry pick. It requires merging back to dev branch for some reason. I would like to know if there is a better to do it?

Not anymore, with VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020)

> ### [Git: Cherry Pick](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/d9a6977d8a5d2c0f9f0fb28227ac4a022d558c3b/release-notes/v1_52.md#git-cherry-pick)
>
> A new `Git: Cherry Pick...` command lets you cherry pick commits from history.

Simply chose the commits you want from `dev` to cherry-pick to `prod`, right from VSCode.